# Numpy chained index "force" to be view rather than copy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Basically I want this chained slicing to overwrite the value (show the first element as a 2 instead of 1)

```
tst = np.array([1,2,3,4])
msk1 = [True, False, True, False]
msk2 = [True, False]
tst[msk1][msk2] = 2

tst
> array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is that `tst[msk1]` is a copy by slicing, and **not a view**.

You can check it using `tst[msk1].base` that returns nothing (it would return the original array if a view). So when you further slice and modify `tst[msk1][mask2] = 2`, you actually modify the **in memory copy**, not `tst`.

To my knowledge, you [cannot force a view with fancy indexing](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html), so what you want is not directly achievable.

One workaround might be to get the indices of the first mask, and then to slice them with the second mask:

```
idx = np.where(msk1)[0][msk2]
tst[idx] = 2

# print(tst)
# [2 2 3 4]
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized I couldn't force a view and had been playing around with np.where for a while but just couldn't figure it out, it's so simple when laid out in front of you